# Hiding Range of Columns in Excel using VBA based on cell Values

Tags: excel, vba

I need to hide a range of cells using a macro in excel. C11 contains the column index from where I need to start hiding the columns.

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


Dim rocket As Range


i = Range("c11").Value
j = 12

rocket = Range(Cells(5, i), Cells(5, j))

Range("Rocket").Select

Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True


End Sub
```

The code is giving some unexpected error and as I am a novice, so have no clue what needs to be done..

Answer (score 1):

Tree steps to make your code working:

1st. Add `Set` key word in appropriate line which is necessary:

```
Set rocket = Range(Cells(5, i), Cells(5, j))
```

2nd. `Rocket variable` represents range, you will NOT need to call it in this way:

```
Range("Rocket")....
```

but

```
rocket....
```

3rd. Avoid `Select method` and `Selection object` always when possible. Therefore the last two lines replace with this single one (which implements 2nd step, too):

```
rocket.EntireColumn.Hidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

That last answer was awesome! Just for someone else's FYI, here is what worked in Excel 2007. The first line is always 3, but the ending line needed to be a variable. That's where I had the problem. THIS FIXED IT! The last 4 lines before the "End If" do the work. Hope this helps!

```
Dim RowsToHide As Range
Dim RowHideNum As Integer

' Set Correct Start Dates for Billing in New File
Workbooks("----- Combined_New_Students_Updated.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("2015").Activate
StartDateLine1 = Format(START_DATE_1, "ww") - 1 ' Convert Start Date to Week Number
StartDateLine1 = (StartDateLine1 * 6) - 2 ' Convert Start Date to Line Number
If StartDateLine1 >= "10" Then
 Cells(4, "q").Value = ""
 Cells(StartDateLine1, "q").Value = STATUS_1
 Cells(StartDateLine1, "z").Value = "START DATE " + START_DATE_1
 RowHideNum = StartDateLine1 - 2
 Set RowsToHide = Range(Cells(3, "a"), Cells(RowHideNum, "ab"))
 RowsToHide.Select
 RowsToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```